# Save button submitting the form even if its type is "button" and not submit

Tags: button, form-submit

I have a form having bootstrap validation and two buttons. One is of type button(Save) and another is of type submit(Next). When I click on "Next" button without any values then bootstrap validator works fine. But when I correct the error and click on "Save" button instead of "Next" button, form is getting submitted even if "Save" button is of type "button" and not "submit". Can someone suggest what should be done in this case. Form should not get submitted on save button at all.

Answer (score 3):

In your button provide an id, then call it in jquery like this:

```
<script>
    $('#yourButtonId').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

But make it sure that you included a jquery in your web page, or else it will not work.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but I already tried above solution. My problem is different. My flow is working fine when I do not click on Next button before Save. problem arises when When I click on Next button initially(Bootstrap validation causes error on page in this case). When I correct errors and after click on Save button, It saves data as per design but causes form submit even if type of Save is button and not Submit. So according to design After clicking on save button "it should not submit the form".

Comment: For your reference : <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save" onclick="savePatientDetails()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved"></span>Save</button>
<button type="submit" id="next" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>Next</button>

Comment: What is inside of savePatientDetails() are you performing an ajax there?

Comment: Yes, SavePatientDetails() has ajax call inside.

Comment: You can find it here : function savePatientDetails() {
   var hasErrors = $('#patientEditForm').bootstrapValidator('validate').has('.has-error').length;       
        if (!hasErrors) {       
     saveDetails('patientEditForm', 'save', 'savePatientDetails');
        }        
  }

Comment: function saveDetails(form, id, url){
 
  var formData = $('#'+form).serialize();

  $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      data:formData,
      url:url,
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){         
       showSuccessMsg(data);
      },
   error: function(data){
    showErrorMsg(data);          
     }
  });
  
 }

Comment: Did you try to return false on your button click event like this:
$('#yourButtonId').click(function(){ return false; });

Comment: I think much better to remove your onclick function and replace it with click event try this : $('#save').click(function(){ var hasErrors = $('#patientEditForm').bootstrapValidator('validate').has('.h‌​as-error').length; ‌​ if (!hasErrors) { saveDetails('patientEditForm', 'save', 'savePatientDetails'); } return false;});  function saveDetails(form, id, url){ var formData = $('#'+form).serialize(); $.ajax({ type:"post", data:formData, url:url, async: false, dataType: "json", success: function(data){ showSuccessMsg(data); }, error: function(data){ showErrorMsg(data); } }); }